# Adding multiple SecurityGroupIngress rules

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I am trying to create circular dependency security groups. So, first I am creating two security groups. Then I am trying to add inbound rules. But I am unable to add multiple rules for Inbound rules.

```
"SecurityGroup01": {
    "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
    "Properties": {
        "GroupDescription": "SecurityGroup01",
        "VpcId": { "Ref": "VPCID" },
        "SecurityGroupEgress": [
            { "IpProtocol": "tcp", "FromPort": "1", "ToPort": "65535", "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0" },
            { "IpProtocol": "icmp", "FromPort": "8", "ToPort": "-1", "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0" }
        ],
        "Tags": [
            { "Key": "Name", "Value": "SG01" }
        ]
    }
},
"SecurityGroup02": {
    "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
    "Properties": {
        "GroupDescription": "SecurityGroup02",
        "VpcId": {
            "Ref": "VPCID"
        },
        "SecurityGroupEgress": [
            { "IpProtocol": "tcp", "FromPort": "1", "ToPort": "65535", "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0" },
            { "IpProtocol": "icmp", "FromPort": "8", "ToPort": "-1", "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0" }
        ],
        "Tags": [
            { "Key": "Name", "Value": "SG02" }
        ]
    }
},
"SG01InboundRule": {
    "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress",
    "Properties": {
        "IpProtocol": "tcp", "FromPort": "3389", "ToPort": "3389", "CidrIp": { "Ref": "LocalIPAddress" }, 
              "DestinationSecurityGroupId": { "Fn::GetAtt": [ "SecurityGroup02", "GroupId" ] }, 
              "GroupId": { "Fn::GetAtt": [ "SecurityGroup01", "GroupId" ] }
    }
}
```

**Expected  Result**
Add multiple rules

```
"SG01InboundRule": {
    "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress",
    "Properties": [
        "IpProtocol": "tcp", "FromPort": "3389", "ToPort": "3389", "CidrIp": { "Ref": "LocalIPAddress" }, "GroupId": { "Fn::GetAtt": [ "SecurityGroup01", "GroupId" ] }
        "IpProtocol": "tcp", "FromPort": "4200", "ToPort": "4200", "CidrIp": { "Ref": "LocalIPAddress" }, "GroupId": { "Fn::GetAtt": [ "SecurityGroup01", "GroupId" ] }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The resource `AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress` only contains one rule, but you can create multiple of `AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress` and attach them to the same security group.

So you would have:

```
"SG01InboundRule": {
    "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress",
    "Properties": {
        "IpProtocol": "tcp", "FromPort": "3389", "ToPort": "3389", "CidrIp": { "Ref": "LocalIPAddress" }, 
              "DestinationSecurityGroupId": { "Fn::GetAtt": [ "SecurityGroup02", "GroupId" ] }, 
              "GroupId": { "Fn::GetAtt": [ "SecurityGroup01", "GroupId" ] }
    }
}

"SG02InboundRule": {
    "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress",
    "Properties": {
        "IpProtocol": "tcp", "FromPort": "4200", "ToPort": "4200", "CidrIp": { "Ref": "LocalIPAddress" }, 
              "DestinationSecurityGroupId": { "Fn::GetAtt": [ "SecurityGroup02", "GroupId" ] }, 
              "GroupId": { "Fn::GetAtt": [ "SecurityGroup01", "GroupId" ] }
    }
}
```

Comment: This saved me a lot of headache